# How to login into social network using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I need to parse html data of social games in vk.com (it's russian analogue of facebook). I tried to download html page.

```
library(dplyr)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
vk_roleGamesURL <- "https://vk.com/apps?act=genre18&id=18"
download.file(vk_roleGamesURL,
              destfile=vkRoleLocal <- paste0("vkRoleLocal.xml"))
```

After downloading i opened and saw, that it is start login page, where i need to type my email and password. How can i avoid this problem? Can i login via R?

Comment: Beware that scraping is explicitly against the terms of service of many of these services (don’t know about VK in particular). If you care about this, make sure you read them before going ahead.

Answer (score 2):

As this website requires javascript do function properly: Have a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html on how it works.

Basically it is something like the following:

1 Open the Login-Screen

```
require(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" 
                      , port = 4444
                      , browserName = "firefox"
                      )
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://vk.com/apps?act=genre18&id=18")
```

2 Login

```
email <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "email")
pass <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "pass")
email$sendKeysToElement(list("YOUR EMAIL"))
pass$sendKeysToElement(list("YOUR PASS", "\uE007")) #\uE007 is the enter key
```

3 Do what you want to do as a logged in user

Comment: The unicode keys are mapped in RSelenium. They are contained in a variable selKeys (see ?selKeys). When sending keys to elements you can do: `pass$sendKeysToElement(list("YOUR PASS",  key = "enter"))`